# The price did not add if did not scroll down

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The cart list that I currently do have a problem that is when the products in the cart list is more than 4 the total price did not include the rest items' price until I scroll down then the total price will add the rest item's price in but I want that is when user open it already shows the total price of all items without scroll. Hope that someone can help me to figure out where is the problem, Thank you

Below is the code of Cart Activity:

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private TextView txtTotalAmount;
private Button resetbtn;
public CheckBox checkBox;
private static DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
private double MemTotalPrice =0;
private double TotalPrice =0;
private boolean count = true;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);


    initWidgets();
    setOnClickListeners();

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.cart_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    txtTotalAmount = findViewById(R.id.total_price);
}
private void setOnClickListeners(){
    resetbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(CartActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Alert");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to reset?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    DatabaseReference cartListRef =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart List");
                    cartListRef.removeValue();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CartActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            android.app.AlertDialog alert2 = builder.create();
            alert2.show();

        }
    });
}
private void initWidgets()
{
    resetbtn = findViewById(R.id.resetbutton);
}

@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    final DatabaseReference cartListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart List");
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Cart> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Cart>()
            .setQuery(cartListRef.child("Cart")
                    .child(("Products")), Cart.class)
                    .build();

   FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cart, CartViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cart, CartViewHolder>(options) {

       @Override
       protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CartViewHolder cartViewHolder, final int i, @NonNull final Cart cart)
       {
           cartViewHolder.btn_quantity.setNumber(cart.getQuantity());
           cartViewHolder.txtProductPrice.setText("Price = RM"+cart.getPrice());
           cartViewHolder.txtProductName.setText(cart.getProductName());

           cartViewHolder.btn_quantity.setOnValueChangeListener(new ElegantNumberButton.OnValueChangeListener() {
               @Override
               public void onValueChange(ElegantNumberButton view, int oldValue, int newValue)
               {
                 cart.setQuantity(String.valueOf(newValue));
                 cartListRef.child("Cart").child("Products").child(cart.getProductName()).child("quantity").setValue(String.valueOf(newValue));

                   if(oldValue > newValue){
                       TotalPrice = TotalPrice - Double.valueOf(cart.getPrice());
                   }
                   else if(newValue > oldValue){
                       TotalPrice += (Double.valueOf(cart.getPrice()));
                   }
                   count = false;
               }

           });

           if(count){
               TotalPrice += (Double.valueOf(cart.getPrice()) * Double.valueOf(cart.getQuantity()));
           }

           count = true;

            cartViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    CharSequence options [] = new CharSequence[]{

                            "Remove"
                    };
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CartActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Cart Options");
                    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            if (which == 0)
                            {
                                cartListRef.child("Cart")
                                        .child("Products")
                                        .child(cart.getProductName())
                                        .removeValue()
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                            {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful())
                                                {
                                                    Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "Item removed successfully.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;

                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(CartActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                    startActivity(intent);
                                                }

                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                     builder.show();
                }
            });
           txtTotalAmount.setText("Total Price = RM " + df.format(TotalPrice));
       }

       @NonNull
       @Override
       public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
       {
           View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart_items_layout,parent,false);
           CartViewHolder holder = new CartViewHolder(view);
           return holder;
       }
   };
   recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
   adapter.startListening();


}
}
```

---

Firebase real-time database:

```
{
"Cart List" : {
"Cart" : {
  "Products" : {
    "BenQ" : {
      "MemPrice" : "150",
      "Price" : "300",
      "ProductName" : "BenQ",
      "date" : "19 Jan 2020",
      "quantity" : "1",
      "time" : "23:28:08 p.m."
    },
    "Dell" : {
      "MemPrice" : "5000",
      "Price" : "10000",
      "ProductName" : "Dell",
      "date" : "19 Jan 2020",
      "quantity" : "1",
      "time" : "23:27:13 p.m."
    },
    "IBM" : {
      "MemPrice" : "200",
      "Price" : "400",
      "ProductName" : "IBM",
      "quantity" : "1"
    },
    "KDK" : {
      "MemPrice" : "25",
      "Price" : "50",
      "ProductName" : "KDK",
      "quantity" : "1"
    },
    "Logitech" : {
      "MemPrice" : "5",
      "Price" : "10",
      "ProductName" : "Logitech",
      "date" : "17 Jan 2020",
      "quantity" : "1",
      "time" : "03:07:18 a.m."
    }
  }
}
},
"Product" : {
"Product1" : {
  "Barcode" : "112233",
  "MemPrice" : "5",
  "Price" : "10",
  "ProductName" : "Logitech"
},
"Product2" : {
  "Barcode" : "123456",
  "MemPrice" : "5000",
  "Price" : "10000",
  "ProductName" : "Dell"
},
"Product3" : {
  "Barcode" : "778899",
  "MemPrice" : "150",
  "Price" : "300",
  "ProductName" : "BenQ"
  }
 }
}
```

---

Below are the screenshots:

1)In the cart, it has 5 items The total price should be 10760, but it shows 10750 that is the total  price of the 4 items and did not add the price of the 5th item in the cart
 [Before Scroll down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj5G8.png)

2) After scroll down, it added the 5th item's price
  [After Scroll down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNSZU.png)

Comment: please add activity code where you fetched api data ?

Comment: you have to create a function to count total price and pass all product data to that function parameter and run a loop to add price of every product and then pass that total price to adapter to set it on view

Comment: @kam1234 which api data

Comment: Firebase real-time database this one

Comment: post your activity code

Comment: updated is the code that you mean?